# make file_name - returns: CreateProcess(NULL, cc hello.c -o hello, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. ERROR

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am new to c language and I am trying to compile my first program, following a tutorial.

My file hello.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

I use "make hello" command to compile it but I get the error:

```
cc     hello.c   -o hello
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc hello.c -o hello, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'hello' failed
make: *** [hello] Error 2
```

I have MinGW installed and I have it in my environment variables PATH.
I am trying it on Windows 8.

Please any help I would very appreciate.
Maybe there is another way to compile a c files?

Comment: If you run `cc` directly, does it work? If not, you need to make sure that make will use the correct compiler. (Or install one if you haven't)

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your comment! I tried to run "cc" but it is not a recognized command. Would you please recommend me any compiler?

Comment: It's been a bit since I've used MinGW, but I think that depends on how you installed it. If you're using MSYS2, then it'd be something like `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinGW is actually a gcc compiler. So the C compiler is invoked with `gcc` instead of `cc`. Try running this command:

```sh
make hello CC=gcc
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks a lot Brecht!